# Django set "debug" mode depending on URL

Tags: django, django-settings

Does anyone know a good way to handle the debug mode dynamically in Django - `settings.py` ? ..

I want the debug mode to be true if the requested is eg. `test.mydomain.com`

and when i go to `mydomain.com` the debug mode is false.

Is there a way to get the requested URL in the `settings.py` file to make a IF condition?

Comment: Please keep in mind that you should **never** use ``DEBUG = True`` in production: [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/#debug)

Comment: @Leistungsabfall i think, ``test.mydomain.com`` is not production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

django's settings should stay immutable. it is supposed to be so.

you better create two settings,

1. settings.py, (which is already there)
2. debug_settings.py with `DEBUG=True`

and create two wsgi's in your django.

1. wsgi.py (which is already there) which refers to settings.py
2. wsgi_debug.py which refers to debug_settings.py

and in your apache config, depending on servername, make it refer to respective wsgi.